# Setup detected an issue during Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. But I'm getting this error:

> Setup detected an issue during the operation. Please click below to
>   check for a solution and help us improve the setup experience.

But I'm not getting any suggestions. Anyone got the same problem?

I've Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue with the following steps;

- Backup your Font folder in C:/windows.
- Delete the contents of the Fonts folder, skipping fonts that can't be
  deleted.
- Run the Installer of Visual Studio (or the Visual Studio update) as
  Administrator
- Restore any fonts after the install has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here which worked for me:

http://devicecontext.blogspot.com/2015/07/wpf-and-broken-fonts.html

```
Open cmd.exe and copy all files from c:\windows\fonts to some other folder (c:\fonts for me).
Open regedit and navigate to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
Delete all font registrations (a little scary).

Open Fonts in Control Panel.
Drag all fonts from c:\fonts to the Control Panel Fonts window (this re-registers all valid fonts).
Restart the computer.
```